# Webfont offered for download on form post

Tags: java, css, jsp, spring-security, webfonts

If have a Spring login form that uses a WebFont. When I submit the login form for the first time, the browser offers the `.ttf` version of the web font for download. If I then abort the download and click the submit button again the login works and I get redirected. This error is reproducible on IE 8 & 9 on every login (no surprise there) and on FF 10 only after clearing the cache. This only happens with the method set to post. Get works fine, but that is obviously no solution for a login form...

Any idea of what might be the cause would be helpful.

The code is pretty straight-forward:

Here's the CSS file:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* first for IE 6/7/8 */
@font-face {
  font-family: KievitWebProBook;
  src: url(/fonts/KievitWebPro-Book.eot);
  src: url(/fonts/KievitWebPro-Book.eot?) format('eot'),
       url(/fonts/KievitWebPro-Book.woff) format('woff'),
       url(/fonts/KievitOffcPro-Book.ttf) format('truetype');
}

body { font-family: KievitWebProBook, sans-serif; }
div.logo { margin-left: auto; margin-right: 150px; margin-top: 100px; text-align: right; }
div.header { width: 90%; margin: 0px auto 20px auto; color: #788995; font-size: 24px; padding-left: 300px;}
div.divider { width: 90%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 5px; background-image: url(/images/gradient5px.png); background-repeat: repeat-x;}
table { margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 300px; width: 330px; background-color: #eaedef; padding: 10px;}
td.header { text-align: center; font-size: large; padding: 5px; }
td.error { color: #0076ae; font-size: small; }
td.errorcode { color: #98a5ae; font-size: small; text-align: right; font-size: 12px;}
td.input input { width: 100%; color: #a6b1b9; font-size: 12px; }
td.submit { text-align: left; width: 50% }
td.subtext { text-align: right; color: #0076ae; font-size: x-small; width: 50%; }
td.subtext a { color: #0076ae; }
```

And here's the JSP:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
%><%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
%><%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
%><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title><spring:message code="login.title"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/css/login.css'/>" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function clearInput(inp) {
        if (inp.value === inp.defaultValue) {
            inp.value = "";
        }
    }

    function restoreInput(inp) {
        if (inp.value === "") {
            inp.value = inp.defaultValue;
        }
    }
    -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo"><img src="<c:url value="/images/logo.png"/>" alt="Logo" /></div>
    <div class="header"><spring:message code="login.title"/></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <form action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="input" colspan="2"><input name="j_username" type="text" onfocus="clearInput(this);" onblur="restoreInput(this);" value="<spring:message code="login.username"/>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="input" colspan="2"><input name="j_password" type="password" onfocus="clearInput(this);" value="<spring:message code="login.password"/>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="submit"><input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="login.loginbutton"/>"/></td>
            <td class="subtext"><a href="newpass.jsp"><spring:message code="login.newpass"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        <c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
        <tr>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><spring:message code="login.error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="errorcode" colspan="2">Code: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/></td>
        </tr>
        </c:if>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might work -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PTSansNarrowRegular';
    src: url('PTN57F-webfont.eot');
    src: url('PTN57F-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('PTN57F-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('PTN57F-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('PTN57F-webfont.svg#PTSansNarrowRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

This is the extraction from the FontSquirrel's CSS for embedding fonts.
Hope this helps.